# Specifying Tuple in `newtype` Argument

Tags: haskell, newtype

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#the-newtype-keyword) discusses `newtype`.

How does its signature of `Pair b a` mean that the passed-in argument must be a tuple?

```
ghci> newtype Pair b a = Pair { getPair :: (a, b) }
ghci> let p = Pair (5, 10)
```

I'm confused how `b a` indicates a tuple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you pass in a tuple is not in the type, but in its constructor:

```
Pair { getPair :: (a, b) }
```

This is using [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax) to define a `Pair` constructor with a single field called `getPair`, which contains a tuple. You could get a very similar effect by breaking it into two parts:

```
newtype Pair b a = Pair (a, b)

getPair (Pair (x, y)) = (x, y)
```

So the `b a` *does not* force it to be a tuple; that's what the `{ getPair :: (a, b) }` does.

Comment: `s/single field called getTuple/single field called getPair/`

Answer (score 7):

The confusion comes about because you have your data type name and constructor name both specified as `Pair`.  Instead, you could equivalently write

```
newtype Pair b a = MkPair { getPair :: (a, b) }
```

Then you'd construct it with

```
> let p = MkPair ("test", 10) :: Pair Int String
```

---

Constructors and type names don't share namespaces, so they can have the same name without conflicting.  This pattern is often used for newtypes, since the type name is usually a good descriptive name for the constructor as well.  This also works for types declared with the `data` keyword.